# Binary subtraction using two's compliment

Tags: binary

(22)10 - (65)10= (?)2
Perform this operation using 2's compliment method.Use 8bit representation of numbers

Comment: can you specify what are numbers? does that 10 mean base 10 representation of 22 and 65? also what's the work you've done so far? what's the problem you encountered during subtraction process? otherwise simply take a look how 2's complement notation works.

Answer (score -2):

As signed 8-bit numbers 22 is 00010110 and 65 is 01000001. To do subtraction you just use two's complement of what you are subtracting by, which is the same as just inverting it and adding 1. So 01000001 (65) would become 1011111**1**. Now let's add 00010110 (22) and 10111111.

```
   ¹¹¹¹¹
  00010110
+ 10111111
----------
  11010101
```

Now if there were to be a carry in this addition we would ignore but lucky enough there was no extra carry. Our answer is given to us in signed two's complement. If we want to find the decimal value of this answer you first reverse the two's complement by inverting all the bits (00101010) and adding one (00101011). This gives us the decimal value of 43, and since the leftmost bit of our original answer is a 1 that means that it is negative. Giving you -43 or 11010101.

Comment: The result is negative only because there is no carry after addition. It has nothing to do with its MSB being 1.